# PHP compare blob with uploaded file

Tags: php, file-upload, blob

I need to compare a file stored as blob in database with recently uploaded file to check if they are different.

I am stuck cause binary are different even if same file.
This is the code I am using:

```php
$file=file_get_contents($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][0]);
if (is_uploaded_file($file)) {
                $doc = fopen($file, 'rb');
            }
    $retRow = $db->prepare($select_row);
                $retRow->execute();
                $data = $retRow->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    
    if($data[0][$this->blob_embedded->blobField]!==$doc){
    
    //do stuff here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your blob in a string because database will return you a stream resource.

Like for file resource you can use equivalent of file_get_contents() : [stream_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents).

Then when you have contents from your file and your blob, you can compare it.

But i don't think is a good idea to compare file contents like that. Maybe write blob to a temporary file and compare this files with [sha1_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.sha1-file) function.